# Insert custom entity statecode

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I am trying to insert status and statecode for custom entity in CRM 2016.
this is my code:

```
if (entity.LogicalName == "activitypointer")
            {
                if (entity.Attributes.Contains("activityid") & entity.Attributes.Contains("activitytypecode"))
                {
                    entity.LogicalName = entity.Attributes["activitytypecode"].ToString();
                    entity.Id = (Guid)entity.Attributes["activityid"];

                    SetStateRequest setState = new SetStateRequest();
                    setState.EntityMoniker = entity.ToEntityReference();
                    setState.State = new OptionSetValue();
                    setState.State.Value = 2;
                    setState.Status = new OptionSetValue();
                    setState.Status.Value = 100000002;
                    SetStateResponse setStateResponse = (SetStateResponse)service.Execute(setState);
                }


            }
```

When I run this I am getting exception:
***100000002 is not a valid status code for state code new_payState.Completed on new_pay with Id 3fbe9a4a-a733-e611-80cb-001dd8b71c1c***.

When I try to change statuscode to other value 2,3 or other I am getting same exception. How I can find valid code state list for this entity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the database, you can se the possible state/status combinations with this query.

```
select state, status, isdefault 
from statusmap 
where objecttypecode = 4200 --activitypointer
```

The key of the statuscode "100000002" indicates that it is a custom statuscode you have added. Make sure that you have published your customizations.

Answer (score 4):

100000002 is not a valid out of the box status code, which means the attribute was customized and options were added.Verify the state code value to which a status code value of 100000002 is associated with (navigate to Customizations, check statecode/statuscode attribute properties).

If you aren't familiar with your way around CRM, try all of the listed state codes.

List of valid out of the box statecode + status code combinations for activity pointer are:

```
statecode        -   statuscode 
0 (Open)         -   1 (Open)
1 (Completed)    -   2 (Completed)
2 (Cancelled)    -   3 (Cancelled)
3 (Scheduled)    -   4 (Scheduled)
```